# Cautionary Tale: Drupal 8.7.0 upgrade

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Don't do it yet. We had an issue where the drush updb failed.

**A fresh install then drush updb did work** but simply updating drupal and civicrm with composer then running drush updb left database in a state where it could no longer be updated by drush.

I have no idea where the source of the issue is but the updb was complaining about null values in the database.

We ran the drupal8/civicrm install from scratch then updated the db and it worked fine.

Here's a link to the relevant drupal upgrade complaint thread:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3052464

Luckily we try all of these things out in a mint copy of production vm first, before we actually do upgrades. This issue may or may not occur for you. Be careful!!!

-Neil

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. It's at the drupal complaint thread above :-) cheers!

Here's a link to the relevant drupal upgrade complaint thread: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3052464

Comment: This would be more acceptable as an Answer if it linked direct to the relevant comment in that drupal thread that contains the solution